# Google Earth Engine Error b.call is not function

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

[image]

I'm trying to display landsat 8  with Google Earth Engine that are clipped with my shapefile but there's an error. Is there something wrong with my script?

```
    // Function to mask clouds using the quality band of Landsat 8.
var maskL8 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  /// Check that the cloud bit is off.
  // See https://landsat.usgs.gov/collectionqualityband
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

var filter = l8.filterDate('2020-01-01','2023-12-31').map(maskL8).median().clip(table);

var scene = l8.filterDate
var visParams = {bands: ['B5', 'B6', 'B7'], max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(scene, visParams, '567 composite');
```

Comment: From your code snippet, there is no such lines as `b.call`.

Comment: yes i also confused i don't type b.call but there's an error about it

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid:

```
var scene = l8.filterDate
```

You're ultimately trying to display a function; that's not going to work.

Comment: then what should i do to fix it?